# Sequelize : One-to-Many relationship not working when inserting values

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, one-to-many, sequelize-cli

I got a One-to-Many relationship between two objects : Dashboard, and Chart, described like this :

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Dashboard = sequelize.define('Dashboard', {
      id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
  });

  Dashboard.associate = (models) => {
    Dashboard.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'user_id',
      targetKey: 'id'
    });

    Dashboard.hasMany(models.Chart, {
      foreignKey: 'dashboard_id',
      sourceKey: 'id'
    });
  };

  return Dashboard;
};
```

And :

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Chart = sequelize.define('Chart', {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(32),
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      title: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      x_title: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      y_title: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      data_type: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      data_value: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      filters: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
      }
    }
  );

  Chart.associate = (models) => {
    Chart.belongsTo(models.Dashboard, {
      foreignKey: 'dashboard_id',
      targetKey: 'id'
    });
  };

  return Chart;
};
```

So when I want to add a new Dashboard with several charts like this :

```
models.Dashboard.create({
    user_id: 1,
    title: 'Dashboard title',
    charts: [
      {
        title: 'time',
        x_title: 'Days',
        y_title: 'Count',
        data_type: 'count',
        data_value: 'visit',
        filters: '[{"type":"project","values":["1"]},{"type":"language","values":["french"]},{"type":"satisfaction","values":[1,2,3]}]'
      },
      {
        title: 'indicator',
        x_title: '',
        y_title: '',
        data_type: 'count',
        data_value: 'visit',
        filters: '[{"type":"project","values":["1","2","3","4","5","6"]},{"type":"language","values":["french"]}]'
      }
    ]
  }, { include: [models.Chart] }).then(() => {
    res.send({
      'message': 'Dashboard loaded !'
    });
  });
```

The dashboard is inserted into the database, but no charts inserted as well... What is the best way to add records with a one-to-many association using Sequelize ? I just try and try, and read all docs (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#creating-with-associations) but I don't understand this problematic behaviour...

Thank's for your help and your enlightening !

Answer (score 1):

In the defined association

```
Dashboard.hasMany(models.Chart, {
      foreignKey: 'dashboard_id',
      sourceKey: 'id'
    });
```

the `foreignKey` is mentioned as `dashboard_id` but there is no `dashboard_id` in the `Chart` model.

The following code works

```
const Dashboard = sequelize.define('dashboard', {
  title: Sequelize.STRING,
});

const Chart = sequelize.define('chart', {
  dashboard_id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  title: Sequelize.STRING,
});

Dashboard.hasMany(Chart, {
  foreignKey: 'dashboard_id',
  sourceKey: 'id'
});
Dashboard.create({
  title: 'one',
  charts: [
    { title: 'title1' },
    { title: 'title2' }
  ]
}, { include: [Chart] }).then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank's you for your help, but I need a bidirectional One-To-Many association.

By doing your way, I still got the same problem... I don't understand why, maybe it's because I use Sequelize CLI with one JS file per object definition... Or the Sequelize sync function is not called at the right moment.

The weird thing is that when I insert the Dashboard first and then I insert the charts by defining their dashboard_id it works well. Like this:

```
models.Dashboard.create({ 
    user_id: 1,
    title: 'Visites Histopad'
}).then((dashboard) => {
    models.Chart.bulkCreate([{
        dashboard_id: dashboard.id,
        title: 'time',
        x_title: 'Days',
        y_title: 'Count',
        data_type: 'count',
        data_value: 'visit',
        filters: '[{"type":"project","values":["1"]},{"type":"language","values":["french"]},{"type":"satisfaction","values":[1,2,3]}]'
      },
      {
        dashboard_id: dashboard.id,
        title: 'indicator',
        x_title: '',
        y_title: '',
        data_type: 'count',
        data_value: 'visit',
        filters: '[{"type":"project","values":["1","2","3","4","5","6"]},{"type":"language","values":["french"]}]'
      }
    ]).then(() => {
      res.send({
        'message': 'Dashboard loaded !'
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out... I was using an old version of Sequelize, because seuquelize-cli load the 2.0.0-rc8 version and not the last one (4.0.0). So everything works perfectly now.