# Create one to many relationship object in database using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I've searched a lot and didn't find any answer.
My english isn't that good so i might not used the best keywords...

Here is my problem, is there a way to insert in one query an object like this ?

I have a one to many relationship between two objects define like this :

foo can have many bar

bar can have one foo

```
export const foo = sequelize.define('foos', {
    idfoo: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    value: Sequelize.STRING,
    valueInt: Sequelize.INTEGER
})

export const bar = sequelize.define('bars', {
idbar: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
},
    value: Sequelize.STRING,
    valueInt: Sequelize.INTEGER
})

foo.hasMany(bar, {
    foreignKey: 'idfoo'
});
bar.belongsTo(foo);
```

Imagine you got this object you want to insert in your db. How would you do it ?

```
{
    "value": "test",
    "valueInt": 5,
    "bars": [
        {
            "value": "test",
            "valueInt": 6
        },
        {
            "value": "test",
            "valueInt": 7
        }
    ]
}
```

I have read Sequelize documentation i didn't find any clue of this issue (or maybe i've missed it ).

I wasn't be able to make this solution works [Sequelize : One-to-Many relationship not working when inserting values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50685266)

Actually here is my Sequelize create function, i thought Sequelize handled all the imports alone (pretty naive i guess)...

```
static async post(body) {
    await foo.create(body);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to indicate the same `foreignKey` option for both paired associations:

```js
foo.hasMany(bar, {
    foreignKey: 'idfoo'
});
bar.belongsTo(foo, {
    foreignKey: 'idfoo'
});
```

That way Sequelize can make sure these two models linked by the same fields from both ends.
Second, in order to insert both main and child records together you need to indicate the `include` option in the `create` call with `bar` model:

```js
static async post(body) {
    await foo.create(body, {
     include: [bar]
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion is working perfectly with the code example i gave :) Now I need to understand why it's not working in my project !

Comment: Just check if all `foreignKey` options are set properly and the same for pairs and of course that your property used to indicate child records in `create` call corresponds to the name of included model